# What is a sequence constructor in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt, constructor

I looked a the spec and some other documents but I dont really get it. I get that now there are sequences instead of nodesets, okay, but what is a sequence constructor (or may more easily: what ISNT a sequence constructor)?

The spec just says

> [Definition: A sequence constructor is a sequence of zero or more
>   sibling nodes in the stylesheet that can be evaluated to return a
>   sequence of nodes and atomic values. The way that the resulting
>   sequence is used depends on the containing instruction.]
>
> > Many XSLT elements, and also literal result elements, are defined to
> >     take a sequence constructor as their content.

I kinda get that xsl:sequence constructs a sequence, but why is the content of xsl:element a sequence constructor? And what isnt a sequence constructor then?

Thanks for clarifications!

Answer (score 2):

See further down in the spec where it says

> The term sequence constructor replaces template as used in XSLT 1.0.
>   The change is made partly for clarity (to avoid confusion with
>   template rules and named templates), but also to reflect a more formal
>   definition of the semantics. Whereas XSLT 1.0 described a template as
>   a sequence of instructions that write to the result tree, XSLT 2.0
>   describes a sequence constructor as something that can be evaluated to
>   return a sequence of items; what happens to these items depends on the
>   containing instruction.

So where the XSLT 1.0 grammar had for instance

```
<!-- Category: top-level-element -->
<xsl:template
  match = pattern
  name = qname
  priority = number
  mode = qname>
  <!-- Content: (xsl:param*, template) -->
</xsl:template>
```

allowing as the contents of an `xsl:template` rule a number of `xsl:param` plus a `template` the XSLT 2.0 grammar now has

```
<!-- Category: declaration -->
<xsl:template
  match? = pattern
  name? = qname
  priority? = number
  mode? = tokens
  as? = sequence-type>
  <!-- Content: (xsl:param*, sequence-constructor) -->
</xsl:template>
```

defining the contents of an `xsl:template` rule as a number of `xsl:param` plus a sequence constructor.

That way it is also obvious that `xsl:param` is not a sequence constructor for instance but of course as its content has a sequence constructor.

As for how to construct a sequence, well you can do that with literal result elements and of course with instructions like `xsl:value-of`, `xsl:element`, `xsl:attribute` and so on, as well as with `xsl:sequence` (to allow you to construct and return (sequences of) primitive values and not only nodes, as it was only possible in XSLT 1.0).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much anywhere you can put a literal result element is a sequence constructor, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <a></a>
</xsl:template>
```

...or

```
<xsl:variable name="a">
   <a></a>
</xsl:variable>
```

...but not

```
<xsl:choose>
   <a></a>
</xsl:choose>
```

...because the `xsl:choose` instruction doesn't allow it:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <!-- Content: (xsl:when+, xsl:otherwise?) -->
</xsl:choose>
```

So, sequence constructors are places where values, and instructions that create values, go.